# What is the String class internally?

Tags: java, string, linked-list

Is the String class internally represented and used as a Linked List implementation? I am wondering about what the class's methods and everything are. Does anyone have a link or file that shows the entire String class?

I am studying for an exam, but would like a deeper understanding behind how this class works.

Comment: The source code is publicly available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current JDK 8 sources for String are here:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b119/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

I believe the Java source code is a complete implementation of String, although there are some special cases in the Hotspot JVM where hand-tuned code is called in preference to the Java code. For example, this seems to occur for compareTo(), indexOf(), and equals().

**Update.** And no, it does not use LinkedList internally.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source for OpenJDK's version:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java

Comment: At least find a more recent one.

Answer (score 2):

from the source code of jdk:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];
    ....
}
```

String is backed up by a char array. In java, Strings are constant, their values cannot be changed after they are created